# Three.js - dynamic skeleton animation with BVH and JSON-model (not baked)

Tags: javascript, json, animation, three.js

**Brief description: How can a JSON-character-model be dynamically animated using Three.js and a BVH-motion capture-file? As in: The animation is not baked into the JSON-file but rather loaded and parsed from the BVH-file using BVHLoader.js**

I got as far as loading the BVH-file, attaching its data to the skeletonHelper, extracting the bone-positions, animating some boxes based on their position (for testing pursposes) and loading a (hopefully?) rigged JSON-model. **See the demo here: https://www.patrik-huebner.com/repo/JSON-BVH/**

*See a GIF of the animation here: https://www.patrik-huebner.com/repo/JSON-BVH/demo.gif (sadly, I can't yet post images)*

I did quite some extensive research on this topic and while there are quite a lot of helpful tips[1] on stackoverflow on exporting a mesh from Blender to JSON using the Three.js-exporter and baking in animations, I was not able to figure out how to

a) set up a JSON-file / rigged model / it's skeleton/bones so that I can dynamically animate it (I used a rigged, low-poly from blendswap.com/blends/view/21948). Are there any recommended settings? In order to be able to load the file at all I have to check the "export scene"-option which I'm not quite certain why that should be necessary.

b) map the BVH-data to the JSON-model

If you have any advice and / or code-samples I can use - or at least some resources or keywords that I can research, I'd be most thankful !

**Using the supplied BVHLoader.js I am able to load the animation and attach it to the skeletonHelper**

```
            var loader = new THREE.BVHLoader();
            loader.load( "models/pirouette.bvh", function( result ) {
                skeletonHelper = new THREE.SkeletonHelper( result.skeleton.bones[0] );
                skeletonHelper.skeleton = result.skeleton; // allow animation mixer to bind to SkeletonHelper directly

                boneContainer = new THREE.Group();
                boneContainer.add( result.skeleton.bones[ 0 ] );

                scene.add( skeletonHelper );
                scene.add( boneContainer );

                mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( skeletonHelper );
                mixer.clipAction( result.clip ).setEffectiveWeight( 1.0 ).play();
            } );
```

**Though I am rather certain this is not how its done: I can access the Vector3-data of the skeletonHelper and animate some test-cubes based on those positions** (compare code-sample above and my supplied GIF-animation)

```
            for (var i = 0; i < skeletonHelper.bones.length; i++) {
                var myPos = skeletonHelper.bones[i].getWorldPosition();
                cubeGroup.children[i].position.x = myPos.x;
                cubeGroup.children[i].position.y = myPos.y;
                cubeGroup.children[i].position.z = myPos.z;
            }
```

**Finally, I load the JSON-file and add it to the scene using THREE.ObjectLoader (as the THREE.JSONLoader would not accept my exported model)**

```
            // Load the rigged JSON-file based on this character http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/21948
            // converted to JSON with the Three.json-export-plugin
            var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
            var s = 50;
            loader.load(
                    "models/lowPoly-rigged.json",
                    function ( obj ) {
                            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
                            scene.add( obj );
                            obj.position.y = 0;
                            obj.children[0].material = material;
                            obj.scale.set(s,s,s);
                    },
                    function ( xhr ) {
                            console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
                    },
                    function ( xhr ) {
                            console.error( 'An error happened' );
                    }
            );
```

But now: How do I animate the model using the loaded BVH-data. Do I have to match the amount of bones from the JSON-model to the BVH? Can I just supply some data to the model and have it happen "magically"? I have seen some online demos that load BVH-files dynamically and pass the data to a model[2]

[1] Stuff I did research (sadly, I can't post more links) that did not help, is not quite specific to what I am looking to achieve:

- stackoverflow.com/questions/20433474/dynamic-bones-animation-in-three-js
- stackoverflow.com/questions/29970791/animate-makehuman-character-with-bvh-using-three-js
- stackoverflow.com/questions/40719572/three-js-wrong-bones-orientation (this did look the most helpful as it is actually about combining a loaded BVH-file and a model but researching/implementing the code with my own model lead to error-messages about the material which points to some misunderstanding of mine in the export-process from Blender to JSON)

[2] Some resources that were able to handle BVH-files and could attach those animations to a model:

- BVH Player by Aki A. on chromeExperiments: chromeexperiments.com/experiment/bvh-player
- lo-th.github.io/root/blending2/index_bvh.html

Again, thanks a lot for any input!

Comment: Just to clarify: JSON is not a necessity. OBJ or other formats would be more than acceptable as well if they are easier to implement.

Comment: I'm actually just trying to manipulate the bones of a skeleton by directly setting its quaternion. Do you know if its possible ? I haven't used three.js before, so was wondering if you could point me in the right direction.